# How to avoid the "perhaps a missing \item." message in itemize/enumerate

Tags: errors, lists

If one has a itemize environment, with no items inside :

```
\begin{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

the compilation will complain "perhaps a missing \item". I would like to modify the environment itemize (or enumerate) such that in case there is no `\item`, the compilation doest NOT fail, and simply display nothing.

**EDIT**
I think that by trying to extract a MWE from my actual problem, i missed the point. So, i reformulated the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43751/10157).

Comment: Where is the sense in that (if the question is allowed)?

Comment: Maybe you are more interested in something like `\trivlist\item\relax ... \endtrivlist`

Comment: maybe...if i knew what \`trivlist` is...

Answer (score 5):

You can deactivate it as follows, though I'm not really sure why anyone would want to do this!

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@noitemerr\relax
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{itemize}
\end{itemize}
More text.
\end{document}
```

If you need to reactivate it later, you need to save the original definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@oldnoitemerr\@noitemerr %Save the command definition                      
\newcommand\noitemerroroff{\let\@noitemerr\relax}
\newcommand\noitemerroron{\let\@noitemerr\@oldnoitemerr}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Some text.
\noitemerroroff
\begin{itemize}
\end{itemize}
More text.
%                                                                               
\noitemerroron
\begin{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, and how can you reactivate it ?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: It's quite funny to read it as `no more items moron!`. A little bossy for our good old pal LaTeX :P

Answer (score 1):

These environments are part of the LaTeX kernel, and thus not easily changeable or tweakable without delving into the implementation. (See Ian's answer.) One solution would be to define your own command and use the `ifthen` package:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\safeitemizecmd}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}}}%
}
```

Note that this solution expands the parameter `#1` twice, just for checking if it's empty. You can avoid this by using `\expandonce` from the `etoolbox` package:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\safeitemizecmd}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\expandonce{#1}}{}}{}{\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}}}%
}
```

Then, `\safeitemizecmd{\item ...}` would typeset an itemized environment, and `\safeitemizecmd{}` would typeset nothing.

If you want to use an environment, use the command created above:

```
\newenvironment{safeitemize}{\safeitemizecmd\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

The `\bgroup` and `\egroup` commands are essentially equivalent to braces.

Comment: I don't think that `itemize` is part of plain TeX.

Comment: Not part of, but maybe implemented in?

Comment: Not exactly. Plain TeX is a format for TeX. LaTeX is another. See [Levels of TeX](http://www.tug.org/levels.html).

Comment: What would be the proper way to write it?

Comment: I'd say that `itemize` is part of the LaTeX kernel.

Answer (score 1):

what do you actually want to happen?

Given

```
xxx

aaa\begin{itemize}\end{itemize}bbb

yyy
```

then do you want to get a middle paragraph of `aaabbb` as if the empty environment wasn't there? Do you want (just) a paragraph break, do you want a paragraph break and the display spacing that an itemize environment normally gets above and below?, or do you want (the distinctly odd) output that you actually get from LaTeX, but without the error message?

All those things are (probably) possible but some are easier than others.

Comment: I'm realizing, that extracting a MWE from my original code, i missed the essential point of my problem. So i have to reformulate the question. But yes, i want to get `aaabbb`. And for this, the solution of user946850 could work...