# Problem with expansion of \BODY

Tags: environments, expansion

In the following MWE, the command `\testStringNotEmpty` tests if the argument is empty. This test is robust in the sense that the argument can contain a command or an environment... 
The environment `monenv` willy display "Empty" if the body (which i capture in \BODY) is empty, and "not empty" in the other case.
My problem is that if the body of `monenv` is the command `\macom` which expands to "empty", then it has a different behaviour than the one i expected. This is probably because one should sort of completely expand `\BODY` before to call `\testStringNotEmpty`, and my attempt with the \expandafter does not seem to work...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\testStringNotEmpty}[1]{%
      \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{}=\z@
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \fi
    }
\makeatother

\NewEnviron{monenv}%
{%
\expandafter\testStringNotEmpty\expandafter{\BODY}%
{Environment = NOT empty}%
{Environment = Empty}%
}
\newcommand{\macom}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{monenv}
\end{monenv}

\begin{monenv}
\macom
\end{monenv}

\begin{monenv}
\macom
\macom
\end{monenv}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT** : 
Using the solution of egreg to expand `\BODY` in the environment `monenv`, i encounter now some problems if the content of `monenv` is more complicated (and reflect now my actual code).

So, i redefine `monenv` according to egreg's solution. I define the following command :

```
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{%
\testStringNotEmpty{#1}{hint : #1}{}}
```

and i test it with :

```
\begin{monenv}
\hint{}
\end{monenv}

\begin{monenv}
\hint{}
\hint{}
\end{monenv}
```

which gives me "empty" for the first one (as expected) and "NOT empty" for the second one, which i don't want...

Comment: There is a space between the two `\hint{}`: this makes the contents non empty.

Comment: What would be your advice, for removing all the empty spaces from \BODY ? I think about `\DTLsubstituteall`...

Comment: It's really quite hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{monenv}
  {\begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
     \noexpand\testStringNotEmpty{\BODY}}%
   \x{Environment = NOT empty}{Environment = Empty}%
  }
\makeatother
```

In this way `\BODY` will be "almost completely expanded". One can't use `\edef` as would be more natural, because if something like `\textbf` happens to be in the body of the environment, `\edef\x` would fail miserably.

When `\x` is expanded you'll get

```
\endgroup\testStringNotEmpty{<expansion of \BODY>}{true}{false}
```

and the `\endgroup` will correspond to the previous `\begingroup` (and remove the definition of `\x`).

Comment: ok. I try to get now closer to my original problem, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

The body is not expanding because of the `\unexpanded` in your definition, if you remove that you get empty for all these cases, but then some things would expand in the body that perhaps you don't want expanded. It all depends....

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}    
\newsavebox\BBox
\NewEnviron{monenv}%
 {\savebox\BBox{\BODY}
  \ifdim\wd\BBox=0pt\relax 
  Environment = empty \else Environment = Not Empty: =\BODY= \fi}
\newcommand\macom{}
\begin{document}

\begin{monenv}
\end{monenv}

\begin{monenv}
\macom
\end{monenv}

\begin{monenv}
\macom
\macom
\end{monenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my MWE i have a test "IF BODY not empty", but this was only for the MWE. In fact i have a more complicated test, this is why i can't use a "simple" `\ifx ... \relax`

Comment: then save the contents in a box and compare its width. See edited answer.