# In the resume document class, how to create a subsection without items?

Tags: sectioning, lists, enumerate, resume, cv

I have a document in which I have subsections for which I might or not have items to enumerate:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style  
\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Section1}

\begin{rSubsection}{Sub1}{}
{}{}
\item[] MyItem1
\item[] MyItem2
\end{rSubsection}

\begin{rSubsection}{MyEmptySubsection}{}
{}{}
\end{rSubsection}

\begin{rSubsection}{Sub2}{}
{}{}
\item[] MyItem1
\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that it does not accept a subsection such as the second one in which there is no item. How can I fix that ?

*(Note that I want to keep the exact same font, spacing etc between every subsection)*

The ***resume.cls*** can be found there:
https://github.com/treyhunner/resume

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you. And a link to `resume.cls` might be helpful too: it is not a standard class and googling for it throws several different results.

Comment: Hmm.. internally `rSubsection` creates a new environment from `list`, I was hoping it wrapped `itemize` since [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86547/14593) could have applied. I'm not familiar with `list` I'm afraid.

Comment: That template is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good way to do this would be to create a new environment for a subsection that is designed to be empty, and just call it something new, such as `rEmptySubsection`.  Looking at [the source for the class you are using](https://github.com/treyhunner/resume/blob/master/resume.cls), here is what the environment for the `rSubsection` with a list looks like:

```
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Default Layout: %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %%    Employer (bold)                     Dates (regular)    %%
  %%    Title (emphasis)                Location (emphasis)    %%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  {\bf #1}                 \hfill                  {    #2}% Stop a space
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{
  \\
  {\em #3}                 \hfill                  {\em #4}% Stop a space
  }\smallskip
  % \cdot used for bullets, items non-indented
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em}
  \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}
}{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em}
}
```

Starting with the same idea, and assuming you only want to remove the list from the environment, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style  
\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

% Item-less subsection
\newenvironment{rEmptySubsection}[4]{
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Default Layout: %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %%    Employer (bold)                     Dates (regular)    %%
  %%    Title (emphasis)                Location (emphasis)    %%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  {\bf #1}                 \hfill                  {    #2}% Stop a space
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{
  \\
  {\em #3}                 \hfill                  {\em #4}% Stop a space
  }
  % empty
}{
}

\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Section1}

\begin{rSubsection}{Sub1}{}
{}{}
\item[] MyItem1
\item[] MyItem2
\end{rSubsection}

\begin{rEmptySubsection}{MyEmptySubsection}{}
{}{}
\end{rEmptySubsection}

\begin{rSubsection}{Sub2}{}
{}{}
\item[] MyItem1
\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

In this way, you can customize the environment, and decide on spacing.  You could even create a different kind of subsection altogether if you like.  I hope this helps.